# Can I access sys.argv in python in interactive mode?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, argv

I'd like to do something like:

```
% python foo bar
import sys
sys.argv
```

to get:

```
%  ['foo', 'bar']
```

but of course python dies when you enter an argument which is not a script or goes into non interactive mode if you do.

Can I do this somehow?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `-` as script name:

```
python - foo bar
```

Test:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv
['-', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$ python - asdf asdf
Python 2.7.6 (default, Feb 15 2014, 23:06:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140206 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv
['-', 'asdf', 'asdf']
>>>
```

Comment: +1 thanks for answering - ndpu got in 20s earlier... !

Answer (score 2):

Run python this way:

```
python - foo bar
```

Then

```
import sys
sys.argv
```

will work :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just set it manually for testing in IDLE:

```
try:
    __file__
except:
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], 'foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: i thought about that, but i'm really an occasional python programmer and i'd like to verify i'm using the array properly.  i usually just write the print statement and run a script, but it would be nice to do this on the command line...

Comment: but running `python foo bar` won't run python